# Vertical spacing between elements with 100vh

Tags: html, css

Having a few elements with `height:100vh`, they show a vertical spacing when containing elements.

```
<section>
  <p>A</p>
</section>
<section>
  <p>B</p>
</section>
```

With the styling:

```
section {
  height:100vh;
}
```

You can se an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/uvbgj8xr/4/), the yellow background is visible above each element, even though the margin of the sections is set to 0.

How can the spacing be removed?

Comment: always normalize your css: http://jsfiddle.net/uvbgj8xr/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `overflow:auto;` to `.content>section`

```
.content>section {
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
overflow:auto;
}
```

alternatively you can remove the margin from all elements but then you have to edit both margin and padding to the element which may need it.

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Each browser will have a default user agent style sheet that will add some margin to all h1 elements for example, so you can remove it overriding the user agent style sheet rules for the elements you need.

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
}
```

You can avoid these kind of issues by using a **reset.css** file to reset all different browsers default margin and padding for instance.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `h1` and `p` tags have default margin (or margin collapsing‌​).

**Margin collapsing**

Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing. by [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

**JSFiddle** **-** **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uvbgj8xr/6/)**

You could do like this to remove the margin:

**CSS:**

```
h1, p {
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Not just because `h1` and `p` have default margin, but because **[margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example. Please change ***html,body*** with ******* in css rule.

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```